# YAML for tmuxinator mapping values inside string

Tags: yaml, tmuxinator

I have the following YAML for tmuxinator:

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/st.yml
name: st
root: ~/learn/gnu-smalltalk
attach: false

# Runs before everything. Use it to start daemons etc.
on_project_start:
  - emacs --daemon=gst --title=GST
  - export EDITOR="emacsclient --server-file=gst -c -n"
  - export VISUAL=$EDITOR
  - $EDITOR &;
  - gst-load -iI shampoo.im Shampoo
  - gst-remote -I shampoo.im --daemon
  - gst-remote -e "Shampoo.ShampooServer startOn: 9090 login: 'st' pass: 'st'"

on_project_exit:
  - tmux -CC attach -t st

windows:
  - console-emacs-dev:
      - export EDITOR="emacsclient --server-file=gst -c -n"
      - export VISUAL=$EDITOR      
      - echo "A currar"
  - exercism:
      - export EDITOR="emacsclient --server-file=gst -c -n"
      - export VISUAL=$EDITOR
```

I have two errors that I cannot solve, first is:

```
 st.yml    14  61 error           mapping values are not allowed in this context (yaml-ruby)
```

I tried to scape the character ':',

```
gst-remote -e "Shampoo.ShampooServer startOn: 9090 login\: 'st' pass\: 'st'"
```

but the same occurs

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Although [YAML escape sequences](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092) are a superset of those of the C language, you still cannot escape `:`.

Assuming that `gst-remote` is executed through some shell, what you need to do is escape the backslash:

```
gst-remote -e "Shampoo.ShampooServer startOn: 9090 login\\: 'st' pass\\: 'st'"
```

I would not try and much around with `&` and assume there is a shell being called that properly processes that. Instead use `emacsclient`'s option `--no-wait`:

```
   -n, --no-wait
          returns immediately without waiting for you to "finish" the buf‐
          fer in Emacs.
```

You should also use `.yaml` as extension for your YAML files. Not only has that been the [recommended  extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML since 2006, it also prevents confusion with [files in the YML format](https://fdik.org/yml/).

Comment: I'm using zsh, Maybe that is the poroblem, but this is not working for me, I'm getting the same error. the emacs tip goes well

Comment: @anquegi You should have split your question into two posts, instead of combining two non-related items, that way you could have accepted one of the two and that way let people know that that part of the problem was solved. Are you sure `Shampoo.ShampooServer` doesn't expect `login:st` without a space after the colon?

Comment: yes you are rigth probably this question should be two different questions, In the docs of Shampoo, it hows the string as you see here

Comment: Can you just start a shell and from that try and invoke the whole `gst-remote ...` line. Once you know what works (add the outcome as an edit to your question), it might help others more familiar with tmuxinator to help ( I use the Python based `tmuxp` for this kind of stuff myself (also YAML based BTW))

Comment: I know that this commands work in a shell, it works well, so now I want to automate with tmuxinator, Your are right I'm going to edit this question

Answer (score 0):

This error is a known problem in YAML syntax error when string contains a colon + space, but when using Ansible, after reading [the bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2769) the solution that works was to scape the space character after the  colon character ':', also in tmuxinator [it was a problem](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/515)

```
  - gst-remote -e "Shampoo.ShampooServer startOn:\s9090 login:\s'st' pass:\s'st'."
```

This works for ansible/phyton but not for ruby/tmuxinator

This solution doesn't' work for me, I tried to escape de space inside string \ , \s, or even \u0020, nothing worked the final thing was reading this two posts, it seem that ruby and python use this string in a different way, with ruby I get this error sometimes `undefined method`shellescape' for Hash`.

So I continue looking and

[Explanation YAML 1](https://interviewbubble.com/solved-how-to-escape-indicator-characters-or-in-yaml-escaping-colons-in-yaml/)

[Explanation YAML 2](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html)

from the first link:

> Plain scalars(value field) must never contain the “: ” and “ #”
>   character combinations. Such combinations would cause ambiguity with
>   mapping key: value pairs and comments.
>
> In addition, inside flow collections, or when used as implicit keys,
>   plain scalars must not contain the “[”,  “]”,  “{”,  “}”  and “,”
>   characters. These characters would cause ambiguity with flow
>   collection structures.
>
> You can try these options:
>
> > YAML
> >
> > - url: 'http://www.example-site.com/'
> > - url: "http://www.example-site.com/"
> > - url:
> >       http://www.example-site.com/
> > - url: >-
> >       http://www.example-site.com/ #Recommended
> > - url: |-
> >       http://www.example-site.com/ #Recommended

So the final, yaml file was:

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/st.yaml
name: st
root: ~/learn/gnu-smalltalk
attach: false

# Runs before everything. Use it to start daemons etc.
on_project_start:
  - emacs --daemon=gst --title=GST
  - export EDITOR="emacsclient --server-file=gst -c -n"
  - export VISUAL=$EDITOR
  - $EDITOR
  - gst-load -iI shampoo.im Shampoo
  - gst-remote -V -I shampoo.im --daemon
  - >-
    gst-remote -V -e "Shampoo.ShampooServer startOn: 9092 login: 'toni' pass: 'toni'."

on_project_exit:
  - tmux -CC attach -t st

windows:
  - console-emacs-dev:
      - export EDITOR="emacsclient --server-file=gst -c -n"
      - export VISUAL=$EDITOR      
      - echo "A currar"
  - exercism:
      - export EDITOR="emacsclient --server-file=gst -c -n"
      - export VISUAL=$EDITOR
```